# Android Video Screen Orientation

Tags: android, xml, video, orientation

I am trying to include some videos in my application but the videos are working in one orientation at a time.

I want to change the orientation according to Sensor.

Here is the code:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.siflte.PriyaActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
</activity>
```

I apply this code but when I change the orientation the video get closed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are aware that when changing the screen orientation the current activity is destroyed and recreated, thus losing its state. There a several options in order to assure continues playing of MediaPlayer after screen orientation.

The simplest option is to declare `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the AndroidManifest. This attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. This can give you the desired result, however, it is regarded as a bad practice and according to documentation using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last-resort.

Another option is to save the cursor position of media player when the orientation change occurs, and in onCreate() recreate the MediaPlayer passing the position and start media player to play from there.

Another option would be to save the entire MediaPlayer object and reuse it after screen orientation.

Take a look over this article, it should give you a starting point on how to handle configuration changes: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html